# How to make angular material expansion panel to expand only one at a time

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a mat expansion panel. I want to make only one expandable at a time. Means when one particular record is expanded, and when i click on another record of mat expansion, then other record of mat expansion should close. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to wrap your expansion panels in a `mat-accordion` (see [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#accordion))

Make sure to set `multi` to `false` to disallow multiple expansion panels to be opened at the same time.

```
<mat-accordion [multi]="false">
  <mat-expansion-panel></mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel></mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Here is a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qyyqeomepoj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-steps-example.ts)

Comment: No no no. I am displaying data using *ngFor. Inside mat-expansion i am displaying table. table data is getting after click of particular record of  mat-expansion. After click id of that row is going and api is hitting.